# Have RStudio run on RRO by default

Tags: r, rstudio, rro, microsoft-r

I installed the beta version of R Open from:

> http://mran.revolutionanalytics.com/documents/rro/installation/

It also installs the usual R GUI and I couldn't not find documentation on the MRAN site to switch to RStudio. Anyone has found a way to have RStudio run on RRO?

Comment: Go to 'tools', 'Global options' and change your R version I believe

Comment: Jason: I can't accept your answer since you added it as a comment.

Comment: No biggie. I like your photo answer better anyhow. Thanks for the support :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks Jason. This is the right move.

[image: Here is the screenshot:]